# Issue resolving nested promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, promise

Below is how I generally use promises and I haven't had any issues thus far until now. The problem here is that the `console.log(this.recipe)` is undefined and when I `console.log(JSON.stringify(recipes))` it shows me its an empty array. This leads me to believe that I am not resolving the nested promises correctly.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.recipeService.getAllRecipesByUserId().then((recipes) => {
   this.allRecipes = recipes;
   this.recipe = this.allRecipes[0];
   console.log(this.recipe);
 });
}
```

The `getAllRecipesByUserId()` function should return a promise of type `Recipe[]`

```
  async getAllRecipesByUserId(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
  let recipes: Recipe[] = [];

  await this.userService.userRecipeIds().then((ids) => {
   ids.forEach((id) => {
     const q = query(this.recipeCollection, where('id', '==', id));
     getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         recipes?.push(doc.data() as Recipe);
       });
     });
   });
  });

   return recipes;
  }
```

userRecipeIds():

```
async userRecipeIds(): Promise<string[]> {
 let user: User = new User();
 const q = query(
   this.userCollection,
   where('userId', '==', this.auth.getCurrentUser()?.uid)
 );

 return await getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => (user = doc.data() as User));
   return user.recipes;
 });
}
```

Am I resolving the promises correctly here ?

EDIT:

I have edited the `userRecipeIds()` method to the following:

```
  async userRecipeIds(): Promise<string[]> {
    const q = query(
    this.userCollection,
    where('userId', '==', this.auth.getCurrentUser()?.uid)
  );

  const docs = await getDocs(q);
  const user = docs.docs[0].data() as User;
  return user.recipes;
 }
```

And then subsequently refactored the getAllRecipesByUserId() to the following:

```
  async getAllRecipesByUserId(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
    let recipes: Recipe[] = [];
    const userRecipes = await this.userService.userRecipeIds();

  userRecipes.forEach(async (recipeId) => {
    const q = query(this.recipeCollection, where('id', '==', recipeId));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      recipes.push(doc.data() as Recipe);
   });
 });

 return recipes;
}
```

I still seem to run into the same problem where the array seems to be empty upon inspection within the `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: 1. I believe using simple async/await approach would help you with understanding of nested promises and make the code more readable.
2. Why. in the userRecipeIds() you assign each time data from the Array to the object user - this way the user object is always being overriden and it will point to the last item in the array, so to last "doc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your code, but for instance this snippet looks wrong. You are iterating over an array an assign each item to a single field called `user`, so at the end, after the forEach will take place, field user will have the value of the last item, so the last `doc` as you call it.

Maybe the whole method should look more like this:

```js
async userRecipeIds(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
 const q = query(
   this.userCollection,
   where('userId', '==', this.auth.getCurrentUser()?.uid)
 );

 const docs = await getDocs(q);
 const recipes = docs.map(doc => doc.data());

 return recipes;
}
```

in case we only want first element:

```js
async userRecipeIds(): Promise<User> {
 const q = query(
   this.userCollection,
   where('userId', '==', this.auth.getCurrentUser()?.uid)
 );

 const docs = await getDocs(q);
 const user = docs[0].data();

 return user;
}
```

Then that's how the other function can maybe look like?:

```js
 async getAllRecipesByUserId(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
  const recipes: Recipe[] = await this.userService.userRecipeIds();

  return recipes;
 }
```

Answer to edited question:
When you need to resolve multiple promises at once, for instance when the promises are created from items of an array. You need to treat the results asynchronously. The foreach method doesn't care about that and will end asap, without waiting for results from your promises inside.
What you should do is use Promise.all method. Store all promises, and resolve them all, making an array of results:

```js
async getAllRecipesByUserId(): Promise<Recipe[]> {
    const userRecipes = await this.userService.userRecipeIds();
    const recipieQueries = userRecipes.map(recipe => {
        const q = query(...));
        return getDocs(q);
    })
    const recipes = await Promise.all(allRecipiesPromises);

    return recipes;
}
```

Comment: The `userRecipeIds` queries the user collection and returns the unique user with the corresponding uid. I don't know how to query a collection and only return the one match of the query. There will only be one match for the query so the foreach essentially only runs once. I'm sure theres a better way to execute that though.

Comment: okay, so maybe if the result has only one element, just return it by using [0] as index?

Comment: Thank you. The code makes more sense now and looks cleaner but I still seem to run into the same issue. I have edited my question with the updated code. Do you have any idea where I could have gone wrong ?

Comment: sure, you have to use Promise.all if I understand your problem correctly :) enjoy

Comment: Truly appreciate you taking the time to assist and explain how my implementation was flawed. It worked like a charm.